# Symfony: How can I add an aggregate field in generator.yml?

Tags: symfony1, configuration-files

I am prototyping my application in Symfony 1.4 using Doctrine. I have two models, encounters and photos. One encounter can have many photos and the correct one-to-many relationship is set up in schema.yml.

I have generated a backend using ./symfony generate:app backend. Everything is working fine but I now want to add a count field to my encounters list which I think I should be able to do in generator.yml. In my Encounters.class.php I have the following method:

```
public function getPhotoCount() {

    return count($this->CcPhotos);
}
```

My questions is how can I add a new field in generator.yml which runs this method. I tried %%photo_count%% but I think this is intended for string substitution.

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           CcEncounters
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          cc_encounters
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list: ~
  filter:  ~
  form:    ~
  edit:    ~
  new:
    display: [_camera_id, longitude, latitude, elevation, New Photos]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this. It was as simple as adding:

```
    display: [id, longitude, latitude, elevation, photo_count]
```

Where 'photo_count' matches an accessor method called getPhotoCount